# MongoDB aggregation pipeline with $lookup on 600k documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm running an extract-transform-load process on ~600K items from a mongoDB hosted in Azure. Currently i have set up an aggregation pipeline that uses `$match $skip $limit $lookup` . I do a whole product count, set a batch size and run the pipeline in a for loop. The problem i'm running into is that after 70 batches or so, the connection times out.

What I've read is that $skip will cause this because every time, mongo has to iterate on all documents instead of jumping to the one that skips the previous batches.

I've tried to add a $sort stage on one of the indexed fields and that has helped a bit but not a lot. Also $match is the first stage and its not applied on an indexed field, which i also understand it might be slowing things down.

My question is, if i index the fields on which i do the $match, will that solve my problem?

Is there any other solution to running aggregation pipelines on large collection?

Here is some of my code

```
export const importPipeline = (batch: number, index: number) => [
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [{ matchingChannelId: { $eq: 10 } }, { isActive: { $eq: true } }],
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: { _id: 1 },
  },
  {
    $skip: batch * index,
  },
  {
    $limit: batch,
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collection1',
      localField: 'id',
      foreignField: 'forgeignId',
      as: 'col1',
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collection2',
      localField: 'id',
      foreignField: 'forgeignId',
      as: 'col2',
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      myField: 1,
      otherFields: 1,
    },
  },
];
```

And then

```
const count = await MongoAdapter.countProducts();
const chunkSize = 1000;
const steps = Math.floor(count / chunkSize);
for (let i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
  console.time(`batch${i}`);
  const items = myCollection.aggregate(productImportPipeline(batch, index));
  console.timeEnd(`batch${i}`);
}
```

Comment: `$lookup` on 600k collections - really?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit documents, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by removing the skip stage and adding another condition to the first match stage
`{ _id: { $gt: <id_of_last_item_in_the_previous_batch> } }`

Each time a batch was fetched I save the id of the last item, then add that to the next pipeline.